# Web app into desktop app with qt-creator

Tags: javascript, html, web, qt-creator

I have a web application that works through the browser but I want to embed it into a QT application it's all HTML JavaScript and CSS.  My question is, can I do this with QT Creator, and if so what do I need in order to get this to work?

If you could point me to any tutorials or websites that will give me more information I would appreciate it. I already checked out QT project.org, but it is lacking seriously in documentation on how to do what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be look at this sample which gives yo start

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Code_examples/

Comment: I appreciate the link, but it's not exactly what I was hoping for.  I was hoping I could just wrap the html5 / jquery / css app in QT to compile it and make it more native looking and cross platform installable.  This appears to need a decent amount of C+ programming capability.